# Snow Leopard Server as a Parallels VM

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop

Basic question. I have a licensed copy of Snow Leopard Server, and I want to run it in Parallels 8 as a guest OS. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run Snow Leopard and Leopard Server as a guest. You cannot, however, run Leopard or Snow Leopard NON-server OS as a guest, as it is prohibited via Apple's EULA.

EDIT: See Parallels KB [here](http://kb.parallels.com/en/112323).