# Error when trying to install Snow Leopard Server in Parallels

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, osx-server

[In a previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/snow-leopard-server-as-a-parallels-vm), it was asked if Snow Leopard Server is supported in Parallels 8, and from Parallels documentation, it would appear that it is.

I am trying to stand up a Snow Leopard Server VM on my Parallels instance, but to no avail. I get a window each time saying, simply, `Mac OS X can not be installed on this computer`.

Has anyone here had success installing SL Server? If so, did you also encounter this error? And, if you saw this error, how did you overcome it?

Comment: Are you using a retail copy of SL server or one that came with a Mac?

Comment: Is there a way to tell from the disk itself?

Comment: The restore disk is generally gray while the retail disk should look [like this](http://regmedia.co.uk/2010/11/29/mac_mini_with_snow_leopard_server_7.jpg).

Comment: OK, I have the retail disk like the one in the linked photo.

Comment: If I have the retail disk, shouldn't I be able to stand up a SLS VM?